# SharePoint extended web application returns IIS landing page

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have extended my SharePoint web app (url below) to the below url (entered at the bottom of the extend web app form).

However, browsing to it gives the IIS landing page. DNS record exists and resolves.

https://sharepointsitesuat.arup.com Default https://sharepointsitesuat.arup.com
http://sharepointsitesint.arup.com  Internet    http://sharepointsitesint.arup.com

Also, do I need host headers for an extended web application? As I believe host headers at the web app level don't work with host named site collections?
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you have given same URL for both it wont work. You have to give different site URL for extended site.

You have to use different host header for extended application.

You can bind different url to extended IIS site to land correctly.

Comment: Yeah I did this and in the end it worked.

Comment: Happy to know your issue resolved.